# Protractor break while of for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop, protractor

I need help with loop beaking.

For my check I did the simple test:

```
while(i < 10) {
    element(by.xpath("//a[contains(@id, 'ma-apply')]")).isPresent().then(function(result) {
        if(!result) {
            helper.one_page_ahead();
        } else {
            console.log('there is on the page');
            break;
        }
    });
    i++;
};
```

This code leads to the error.

I tried to follow advice via StackOverflow and changed break to return.
But this leads to full loop execution (up to 10).

Here is the output:

> [14:17:46] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver Started user
>   skills: AJAX there is on the page there is on the page there is on the
>   page there is on the page there is on the page there is on the page
>   there is on the page there is on the page .
>
> 1 spec, 0 failures Finished in 37.93 seconds

I tried the same with `for` loop like

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //code
    break;
}
```

Would be glad to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is some commentary about why the `while` statement does not work: When you call `isPresent` you are returned a `webdriver.promise.Promise<boolean>`. Since you are in the webdriver control flow, you'll need to throw an error,

```
      browser.get('http://angularjs.org');
      var i = 0;
      var running = true;
      while(i < 3 && running) {
        console.log('while: ' + running + ' ' + i);
        element(by.model('username')).isPresent().then((result) => {
          console.log('element: ' + running + ' ' + i);

          if (result) {
            // huzzah we found it, so lets break the element after the first test
            browser.get('https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial');
          } else {
            running = false;
            throw new Error('no username')
          }

        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
        i++;
      }
```

This basically prints out:

```
[19:07:18] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[19:07:18] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
while: true 0
while: true 1
while: true 2
element: true 3
[Error: no username]
element: false 3
[Error: no username]
element: false 3
[Error: no username]
```

So basically your while loop queues up items in the control flow to execute. These then will get executed asynchronously in order.

I like the suggestion by Sudharsan Selvaraj to do this recursively.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a `recursive` method to achieve what you want, try the below piece of code,

```
function runTillElementFound(totalCount,currentCount){
  var self = this;
  var _element = element(by.xpath("//a[contains(@id, 'ma-apply')]"));
  if(currentCount < totalCount){
     return _element.isPresent().then(function(isElementPresent){
        if(isElementPresent){
           return;
         }else{
           helper.one_page_ahead();
           self.runTillElementFound(totalCount,currentCount++);
         }
      })
  }else{
     return false; //if element not present after Max count reached.
   }
}

this.runTillElementFound(10,0); //this will execute the method untill the required element found on the page.
```

Comment: I agree that recursive is the way to do this. You want to check if the element is present, wait for the result and either recursively call it again or quit.

Comment: I removed this and self, it works, but after second page it throws error "callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL". I tried to set up default_timeout_interval in beforeAll section, but also, this didn't help

Comment: Thanks so much, I only increased interval to 120 seconds)

Comment: Welcome @Halina

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid recursion you could modify the index variable inside the returned promised

```
while(i < 10) {
element(by.xpath("//a[contains(@id, 'ma-apply')]")).isPresent().then(function(result) {
    if(!result) {
        helper.one_page_ahead();
    } else {
        console.log('there is on the page');
        i = 10;
    }
});
i++;
```

};

And I would add a browser.sleep(x) in between each repetion to avoid the code to be run before the result from the promise is evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

i = 10; is not effecting, Still loop iterating